# Vim: Append to each line in a "[I" query

Tags: repeated-commands

I have a large config file, where many different instances of a particular config format appear. I would like to take every line where a particular word appears and add some text after it.

Specifically I have configs that look like this:

```
suite: arc-cts-qual                                                                  
pool: MANAGED_POOL_CTS                                                           
exclude_boards: coral, grunt, octopus, rammus, nami, hatch                           
branch_specs: ==tot-2
```

I would like to find every config that has `MANAGED_POOL_CTS`, and add the line

```
pubsub_topic: "projects/foo/topics/bar"
```

So that it will make the above config look like

```
suite: arc-cts-qual                                                                  
pool: MANAGED_POOL_CTS                                                           
pubsub_topic: "projects/foo/topics/bar"
exclude_boards: coral, grunt, octopus, rammus, nami, hatch                           
branch_specs: ==tot-2
```

If this was a contiguous block of configs, I could do it easily with `:'<,'>s/pool: MANAGED_POOL_CTS/<etc.>/`. But it isn't, so I'd like to be able to act on every line that matched the `[I` query.

Answer (score 3):

Check out `:help global`. It basically filters out the lines that don't match the pattern. So you can do `:'<,'>global/<pattern to select lines based on>/substitute/pool: MANAGED_POOL_CTS/<etc.>/`.

Or `:g/MANAGED_POOL_CTS/normal! opubsub_topic: "projects/foo/topics/bar"`. (Edited with @statox's example)

Or, you could execute a macro. Something like: `:global/<pattern>/normal @w`

Comment: I know that exists. It doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @JacobKopczynski I don’t understand. You can do as you described with a global + macro. Please, what is not succeeding?

Comment: The command you supply does not apply to the situation I presented.

Comment: @JacobKopczynski that is false. Use a macro to insert text underneath the current line. Would you like me to edit my answer to include a snippet of what I am saying?

Comment: @JacobKopczynski If you need the user to give more details in your answer you should specify why the answer doesn't apply to your situtation. Here based on Ari's solution I think you could write something like `:g/MANAGED_POOL_CTS/normal! opubsub_topic: "projects/foo/topics/bar"`, if that is not the case please explain why it doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: @AriSweedler For improved clarity your answer would benefit of a more complete explanation of how to combine `:g` and `:s` and of the actual command which would work on the sample provided by OP. Otherwise it might not be easy for all readers to actually use it.

Comment: @statox thank you for the advice. I appreciate the moderation, there was a disconnect that I did not know how to address that I think you have handled wonderfully. If you don’t mind, I will edit my answer to include your example

Comment: I already explained it in the OP.